# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff971e1f920

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

When I run my iOS app on the iPhone 6 simulator on Xcode 6.1 it stops on this line:

```
[cell configure:[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Error:

```
'-[UITableViewCell configure:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff971e1f920'
```

Comment: Google it.  This is a very common exception, and very easy to debug in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you've defined a custom cell subclass with a `configure:` method.

Your subclass isn't being used - that message means you're calling the method on a plain `UITableViewCell`.

The most common cause of this is forgetting to set the cell class in the storyboard. Otherwise, you'll need to show how you're creating `cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You have called the `configure` method on a `UITableViewCell` instance, but this class doesn't have that method.  I suspect that you meant to instantiate your own UITableViewCell subclass that does have that method.